# Why is my simple SQL SELECT statement outputting a hash?

Tags: mysql, sql, hash, client

Recently I started using Beekeper Studio as my MySQL client and I like it, although today I came across a strange behaviour:

```
SELECT CONCAT("Total nr of orders in january is ", COUNT(*)) AS nr_or_payments FROM payments WHERE paymentDate >= '2005-01-01' AND paymentDate <= '2005-02-01'
```

By running this simple query I get a strange hash output rather than what I specified in the concat function

`546f74616c206e72206f66206f726465727320696e206a616e756172792069732035`

I tried to replicate this in different MySQL clients but they seem to be working fine. What's up with this?

Comment: Note that in SQL strings are delimited with single not double quotes.

Comment: which version are you using which client basically it should work https://dbfiddle.uk/l_BhFlyr

Comment: @Stu unfortunately that doesn't work. I get the hash no matter what quotes I surround my string with. In other clients it works well.

Comment: Beekeper studio version is 3.7.1

Comment: What other debugging steps have you taken, what does just `count(*)` return and hard-coding a value in the `concat`?

Comment: If I hardcode 5 it works well

Answer (score 0):

This is probably an issue with your client. The string you posted is not a hash, it's just a string of hex digits, which when we unhex it, turns out to be...

```
mysql> select cast(unhex('546f74616c206e72206f66206f726465727320696e206a616e756172792069732035') as char) as nr_or_payments;
+------------------------------------+
| nr_or_payments                     |
+------------------------------------+
| Total nr of orders in january is 5 |
+------------------------------------+
```

Perhaps Beekeper studio is not set to display the character set returned by MySQL? I don't use that product so I can't suggest how to configure it.

Comment: Yea, I was pretty sure its from my client but still.. really weird behavior

Comment: MySQL has changed their default character set over the past few versions. It's utf8mb4 in the latest MySQL 8.0. This is just a guess, but perhaps Beekeper doesn't know about this update.